Help Identifying Part on 80s Fireplace (insert)
I'm trying to clean my fireplace but this part of it is eluding me.  I'm hoping someone here can help me identify its function and how to clean it.
So on the roof of my firebox, on one side I have a damper that can either be open or closed (not in between).  It's an all-or-nothing style of damper.  On the other side, is a suspended grate.  It's suspended by bolts and nuts.  Removing the nuts from the bolts allows me to remove the grate itself.

Above the grate is another perforated circular section.

After pushing up on it a bit, it appears to be a bowl of some kind.  Though, I can't for the life of me figure out how to remove this to clean.  It's got some heft to it, which seems to indicate there's a heavy buildup of ash in it.

Anybody know what the heck this is?  Or have any ideas as to how I'm supposed to remove it to empty the ashes?
It's worth noting ahead of time that it cannot be removed via the damper side.  The damper opens up towards this weird object, meaning the damper plate itself blocks the way.
Thanks in advance!

It turned out to be a catalytic combustor.  I guess it's used to reduce pollution by eliminating gas and particles before it can leave the stove.  Here's what they look like new:

It's worth noting still that, at least with my model of stove, it cannot be removed.  The stove is mortared in so the entire assembly is inaccessible to me.  However, I believe these are meant to be replaced as they do lose efficacy over time.  Your stove might be different and more easily accessible.  At which point, I would recommend doing further research based on your model.

Good sleuthing work. I'm confused about why yours is irreplaceable, though. Isn't it simply a cylinder like this one which can be slid out?

@isherwood I am very confused as well, it feels like I'm missing something but it's slightly bigger than the hole it sits in, so unfortunately I can't quite get it out without going through the top where the flue connects.
